# Asp.net MVC-How to add order-orderDetails objects using EntityFramework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many, relationship

I have an application that uses one-to-many relationshipped objects like oreder-orderDetails, vith EntityFramework.

I want to use a view, that make it possible to add a new order with some orderDetails objects.

I can create a strongly typed view, that returns an order object wich has a List orderDetails property, but can't populate the orderDetails.

Has anybody a solution, how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use the order table instead of the order view to do this.

Comment: I mean an asp.net MVC view and use EntityFramework that maps database tables to objects

Answer (score 0):

Ok, say you create a view named OpenOrders that inherits from your Order entity.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<OrdersApp.Models.Order>>" %>
```

So then you can display items from your orders list and also add a form that will allow the 
input of Order Details.

So when you post to the page you can receive the Orders object and FormCollection object

```
//
// POST: /Orders/OpenOrders/Details

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult OpenOrders(Order order, FormCollection collection)
```

Then you can create a new OrderDetails object and add it to the Orders object and then save.

```
OrderDetails orderdetails = new OrderDetails()

orderdetails.Description = = collection["OrderDescription"].ToString();
...
...

order.OrderDetails.Add(orderdetails);
orderRepository.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Topic add order orderDetails

  1. Add into Order table
  2. Choose list order in a order table by orderID
  3. Check products in orderdetail for the overlap
  4. loop thought every orderdetail in listorderdetail, add into database
  5. Check some condition, for example: quantity of product in product table ....

-Ok?

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code on my view to populate the data in my List.

```
    @model Webrixs_Portal.Web.Models.CustomViewModels.RefvaluesCreateEditModels   
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EmbadedEditor", "Refvalues", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SavingRefValueInTable" })) 
    {        
      @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ReferenceTranslateion.Count(); i++)
        {

            <div class="row" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;padding-left: 0px !important;  padding-right: 0px !important;margin-top:5px;">

                <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:3px;  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    box-sizing: border-box;">@Model.ReferenceTranslateion[i].RelLanguageName</div>
                <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    box-sizing: border-box;">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReferenceTranslateion[i].RelTe1, new { @class = "k-textbox full" })
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceTranslateion[i].RelID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceTranslateion[i].RelLangID)
            </div>
        }
     }
```

You can use other controls here like listview or gridview etc.

The view model is like:

```
    public class RefvaluesDetailViewModels
      {

    public String RefID { get; set; }
    public List<RefLocaleCreateEditModels> ReferenceTranslateion { get; set; }
       }
```

Maybe this can help you.